# Setting delegate for NSXMLParser giving error for SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nsxmlparser, sigabrt

I am using following code for applying delegate for XML Parsing

```
NSXMLParser *nsXMLParse = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];    
XMLParse *parser = [[XMLParse alloc] initXMLParser];//XMLParse is my custom class, where i used the NSXMLParser protocol 
[nsXMLParse setDelegate:(id <NSXMLParserDelegate>)parser];
```

But this is not working properly. Although its not giving any error here, but its Giving "signal SIGABRT" Error, while Compiling. So please help.

My XML is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Users>
      <User name="Some One" id="a@b.com" pass="123"/>
    </Users>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast to id if XMLParse class implements the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol.

Comment: i am using automatic referencing. So is this the main reason? and how to check the variable is out of scope?

Comment: The variable declared in a method goes out of scope at the end of the method. I added some sample code for you.

Comment: is there an issue from ARC?

Comment: Your class XMLParse may not implement the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol correctly.

Comment: Now i get the exact solution. All things were right except NSXMLParser Protocol Function definitions. Thanks All specially Fruity Geek, to look on the Protocol definition.